# Filemanager checking if fileExists doesn't work in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app that stores images to the documentDirectory. But whenever I am trying to check if the file exists at its path I always get a false response. This was never an issue before iOS 13, but not I am not able to load the images at all, with no error message.

I create my file path like this:

```
func cachePathWithName(name: String) -> String {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let cachesPath: String = paths as String
    let cachePath = cachesPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(path: name)
    createPathIfNecessary(path: cachesPath)
    createPathIfNecessary(path: cachePath)
    return cachePath
}

func getFilePathForURL(url: URL, folderName: String) -> String {
    return cachePathWithName(name: folderName).stringByAppendingPathComponent(path: "\(url.hashValue)")
}

let filePath = getFilePathForURL(url: url1, folderName: "TILE_CACHE")
```

And this is how I check if my file exist at path:

```
if file.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {

}
```

Comment: Are you storing absolute file path or relative path to documents directory?

Comment: Make sure you are using url `path` property instead of `absoluteString` property. The later includes the URL scheme `file://` which would make your path string invalid.

Comment: @JakubSkořepa I updated my answer with the way I create my path :)

Comment: Are you saving those paths ? Note that url hashValue might be different every time you run your app

Comment: @LeoDabus No, not the path itself. But I do the store the hash value of the image url (eg. https://test/images/image.jpg)

Comment: You shouldn't use hashValue

Comment: @LeoDabus I haven't experienced that the hash-value have changed the last four years atleast :O

Comment: Yes but that's why they have always warned to not rely on it

Comment: try this on playground multiple times  `enum Test: Int {`
    `case a, b, c`
`}`
`let test = Test.a`
`test.hashValue`

Comment: @LeoDabus Wow, thats... horrible :O I'll swap that at once - any suggestions on another format? hex? Base64?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817954/hash-different-for-the-same-object-swift-hashable

Comment: @LeoDabus, you are correct. The url-hashing was my issue. Do you know if this changed when iOS 13 launched? Feel free to write an answer to my question, and I'll approve it.

Comment: @MartinR Should we close it as duplicate? I can't vote to close because I did already before OP edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code**

```
let documentsURL = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                      in: .userDomainMask,
                                                      appropriateFor: nil,
                                                      create: true)

            fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(Your File Name)
            if fileURL != nil{
                let fileExists = FileManager().fileExists(atPath: (fileURL?.path)!)
                print(fileExists)
                if fileExists == true{
                    //File is Already in Local Storage
                }
                else{
                    //File is not in Local Storage
                }
            }
```